# Overwriting a hash

Tags: ruby

Why does ruby overwrite class instance variable `@var1`?

```
require 'pp'
class Foo
  @@def = { :key1 => "someval1", :key2 => "someval2" }
  def initialize
    @var1 = @var2 = @@def
    @var1[:key1] = "newval1"
    @var2[:key1] = "newval2"
    pp(@var1)
    pp(@var2)
  end
end
f = Foo.new
```

Output

```
{:key1=>"newval2", :key2=>"someval2"}
{:key1=>"newval2", :key2=>"someval2"}
```

Please say why this happened. And how can I avoid that?

Answer (score 3):

It happens because you set both of the variables to point to the same hash. Editing one would edit all 3 variables (including @@def) because it's all the same hash.

The easiest way to to avoid this is to `clone` the hash.

```
@var2 = @@def.clone
@var1 = @@def.clone
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `@var1` and `@var2` are references to the same object.

If you want them to maintain separate values you need to *copy* `@@def`.